# Compute optimal route for picking ressources

Tags: python-3.x, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Here are the rules (Halite 3):

At each turn, you have to take one decision for your ship. You can either move right, move left, move up, move down or stay still (and gather ressoureces).

Moving your ship cost your ship 10% of current's cell available ressources.
Staying still cost you nothing and you pick 25% of current cell available ressources. If a ship doesn't have enought ressources to pay the 10% to move, he is pinned on the cell for this turn (can't go negative).

My goal: The ship starts at the center (0) and should return at this point with atleast (X amount of ressources) in the less turn possible.

How can I compute the most efficient path (round wise) that my ship should take to achieve my goal ?

Here is some code to compute a random map (the map is random every game) :

```
import random

how_Big = 11 
center_Pos = int(how_Big/2) #how_Big must be even

game_Map = [[random.randint(1,500) for i in range(how_Big)] for x in range(how_Big)]
game_Map[center_Pos][center_Pos] = 0

for y in range(how_Big):
    print(game_Map[y])

[110, 179, 97, 467, 347, 336, 368, 298, 107, 84, 123]
[415, 86, 12, 75, 354, 74, 250, 221, 51, 254, 252]
[368, 235, 389, 1, 155, 186, 149, 135, 458, 243, 344]
[391, 480, 485, 358, 416, 479, 270, 354, 203, 436, 146]
[62, 132, 490, 33, 445, 172, 127, 274, 130, 77, 356]
[239, 11, 459, 245, 214, 0, 324, 162, 58, 394, 202]
[241, 395, 46, 78, 191, 384, 203, 191, 56, 474, 237]
[85, 480, 181, 98, 122, 482, 90, 351, 257, 266, 182]
[398, 125, 195, 423, 219, 290, 140, 166, 413, 499, 428]
[213, 367, 142, 471, 141, 407, 382, 229, 332, 455, 53]
[207, 12, 319, 54, 246, 274, 474, 312, 170, 374, 188]
```

I am not really sure how to start. Is there any known algorithm for this ?

Thanks

Additionnal informations :

- The matrix is the available ressources at the beginning on each cell.
- Ship begins with 0 ressources.
- Ship gains ressources by staying still for a round on a cell
  (collecting 25% of the cell's ressources).
- Ship spends ressources (of his own cargo) by moving (the cost is 10%
  of current cell's available ressources).
- The path can be returned in anyway, for example (moves = ["up",
  "still", "still", "up", "still", "still", "down", "down"]). 
  BruteForcing it would be acceptable.
- X would be the minimum ammount I want my ship's cargo to have when
  returning to center.
- Map always has a center Cell
- Ressources collected or used are always rounded to nearest Int
- Ressources collected by a ship are removed from the cell

Here is an example of what can happen :

```
move_Dict = {
    "up": [-1, 0],
    "down": [1, 0],
    "right": [0, 1],
    "left": [0, -1],
    "still": [0, 0],
}

moves = ["up", "still", "still", "up", "still", "still", "down", "down"]
position = [5, 5]
cargo = 0

print("initial map :")
for y in range(how_Big):
        print(game_Map[y])

for move in moves:
    if move == "still":
        ressources_Collected = round(game_Map[position[0]][position[1]] * 0.25)
        cargo += ressources_Collected
        game_Map[position[0]][position[1]] -= ressources_Collected
    else:
        ressources_Used = round(game_Map[position[0]][position[1]] * 0.10)
        cargo -= ressources_Used
        position = [position[0]+move_Dict[move][0], position[1]+move_Dict[move][1]]

    print(f"ship is at position {position}, cargo = {cargo}")
    for y in range(how_Big):
        print(game_Map[y])
```

Output:

```
initial map :
[110, 179, 97, 467, 347, 336, 368, 298, 107, 84, 123]
[415, 86, 12, 75, 354, 74, 250, 221, 51, 254, 252]
[368, 235, 389, 1, 155, 186, 149, 135, 458, 243, 344]
[391, 480, 485, 358, 416, 479, 270, 354, 203, 436, 146]
[62, 132, 490, 33, 445, 172, 127, 274, 130, 77, 356]
[239, 11, 459, 245, 214, 0, 324, 162, 58, 394, 202]
[241, 395, 46, 78, 191, 384, 203, 191, 56, 474, 237]
[85, 480, 181, 98, 122, 482, 90, 351, 257, 266, 182]
[398, 125, 195, 423, 219, 290, 140, 166, 413, 499, 428]
[213, 367, 142, 471, 141, 407, 382, 229, 332, 455, 53]
[207, 12, 319, 54, 246, 274, 474, 312, 170, 374, 188]
ship is at position [4, 5], cargo = 0
[110, 179, 97, 467, 347, 336, 368, 298, 107, 84, 123]
[415, 86, 12, 75, 354, 74, 250, 221, 51, 254, 252]
[368, 235, 389, 1, 155, 186, 149, 135, 458, 243, 344]
[391, 480, 485, 358, 416, 479, 270, 354, 203, 436, 146]
[62, 132, 490, 33, 445, 172, 127, 274, 130, 77, 356]
[239, 11, 459, 245, 214, 0, 324, 162, 58, 394, 202]
[241, 395, 46, 78, 191, 384, 203, 191, 56, 474, 237]
[85, 480, 181, 98, 122, 482, 90, 351, 257, 266, 182]
[398, 125, 195, 423, 219, 290, 140, 166, 413, 499, 428]
[213, 367, 142, 471, 141, 407, 382, 229, 332, 455, 53]
[207, 12, 319, 54, 246, 274, 474, 312, 170, 374, 188]
ship is at position [4, 5], cargo = 43
[110, 179, 97, 467, 347, 336, 368, 298, 107, 84, 123]
[415, 86, 12, 75, 354, 74, 250, 221, 51, 254, 252]
[368, 235, 389, 1, 155, 186, 149, 135, 458, 243, 344]
[391, 480, 485, 358, 416, 479, 270, 354, 203, 436, 146]
[62, 132, 490, 33, 445, 129, 127, 274, 130, 77, 356]
[239, 11, 459, 245, 214, 0, 324, 162, 58, 394, 202]
[241, 395, 46, 78, 191, 384, 203, 191, 56, 474, 237]
[85, 480, 181, 98, 122, 482, 90, 351, 257, 266, 182]
[398, 125, 195, 423, 219, 290, 140, 166, 413, 499, 428]
[213, 367, 142, 471, 141, 407, 382, 229, 332, 455, 53]
[207, 12, 319, 54, 246, 274, 474, 312, 170, 374, 188]
ship is at position [4, 5], cargo = 75
[110, 179, 97, 467, 347, 336, 368, 298, 107, 84, 123]
[415, 86, 12, 75, 354, 74, 250, 221, 51, 254, 252]
[368, 235, 389, 1, 155, 186, 149, 135, 458, 243, 344]
[391, 480, 485, 358, 416, 479, 270, 354, 203, 436, 146]
[62, 132, 490, 33, 445, 97, 127, 274, 130, 77, 356]
[239, 11, 459, 245, 214, 0, 324, 162, 58, 394, 202]
[241, 395, 46, 78, 191, 384, 203, 191, 56, 474, 237]
[85, 480, 181, 98, 122, 482, 90, 351, 257, 266, 182]
[398, 125, 195, 423, 219, 290, 140, 166, 413, 499, 428]
[213, 367, 142, 471, 141, 407, 382, 229, 332, 455, 53]
[207, 12, 319, 54, 246, 274, 474, 312, 170, 374, 188]
ship is at position [3, 5], cargo = 65
[110, 179, 97, 467, 347, 336, 368, 298, 107, 84, 123]
[415, 86, 12, 75, 354, 74, 250, 221, 51, 254, 252]
[368, 235, 389, 1, 155, 186, 149, 135, 458, 243, 344]
[391, 480, 485, 358, 416, 479, 270, 354, 203, 436, 146]
[62, 132, 490, 33, 445, 97, 127, 274, 130, 77, 356]
[239, 11, 459, 245, 214, 0, 324, 162, 58, 394, 202]
[241, 395, 46, 78, 191, 384, 203, 191, 56, 474, 237]
[85, 480, 181, 98, 122, 482, 90, 351, 257, 266, 182]
[398, 125, 195, 423, 219, 290, 140, 166, 413, 499, 428]
[213, 367, 142, 471, 141, 407, 382, 229, 332, 455, 53]
[207, 12, 319, 54, 246, 274, 474, 312, 170, 374, 188]
ship is at position [3, 5], cargo = 185
[110, 179, 97, 467, 347, 336, 368, 298, 107, 84, 123]
[415, 86, 12, 75, 354, 74, 250, 221, 51, 254, 252]
[368, 235, 389, 1, 155, 186, 149, 135, 458, 243, 344]
[391, 480, 485, 358, 416, 359, 270, 354, 203, 436, 146]
[62, 132, 490, 33, 445, 97, 127, 274, 130, 77, 356]
[239, 11, 459, 245, 214, 0, 324, 162, 58, 394, 202]
[241, 395, 46, 78, 191, 384, 203, 191, 56, 474, 237]
[85, 480, 181, 98, 122, 482, 90, 351, 257, 266, 182]
[398, 125, 195, 423, 219, 290, 140, 166, 413, 499, 428]
[213, 367, 142, 471, 141, 407, 382, 229, 332, 455, 53]
[207, 12, 319, 54, 246, 274, 474, 312, 170, 374, 188]
ship is at position [3, 5], cargo = 275
[110, 179, 97, 467, 347, 336, 368, 298, 107, 84, 123]
[415, 86, 12, 75, 354, 74, 250, 221, 51, 254, 252]
[368, 235, 389, 1, 155, 186, 149, 135, 458, 243, 344]
[391, 480, 485, 358, 416, 269, 270, 354, 203, 436, 146]
[62, 132, 490, 33, 445, 97, 127, 274, 130, 77, 356]
[239, 11, 459, 245, 214, 0, 324, 162, 58, 394, 202]
[241, 395, 46, 78, 191, 384, 203, 191, 56, 474, 237]
[85, 480, 181, 98, 122, 482, 90, 351, 257, 266, 182]
[398, 125, 195, 423, 219, 290, 140, 166, 413, 499, 428]
[213, 367, 142, 471, 141, 407, 382, 229, 332, 455, 53]
[207, 12, 319, 54, 246, 274, 474, 312, 170, 374, 188]
ship is at position [4, 5], cargo = 248
[110, 179, 97, 467, 347, 336, 368, 298, 107, 84, 123]
[415, 86, 12, 75, 354, 74, 250, 221, 51, 254, 252]
[368, 235, 389, 1, 155, 186, 149, 135, 458, 243, 344]
[391, 480, 485, 358, 416, 269, 270, 354, 203, 436, 146]
[62, 132, 490, 33, 445, 97, 127, 274, 130, 77, 356]
[239, 11, 459, 245, 214, 0, 324, 162, 58, 394, 202]
[241, 395, 46, 78, 191, 384, 203, 191, 56, 474, 237]
[85, 480, 181, 98, 122, 482, 90, 351, 257, 266, 182]
[398, 125, 195, 423, 219, 290, 140, 166, 413, 499, 428]
[213, 367, 142, 471, 141, 407, 382, 229, 332, 455, 53]
[207, 12, 319, 54, 246, 274, 474, 312, 170, 374, 188]
ship is at position [5, 5], cargo = 238
[110, 179, 97, 467, 347, 336, 368, 298, 107, 84, 123]
[415, 86, 12, 75, 354, 74, 250, 221, 51, 254, 252]
[368, 235, 389, 1, 155, 186, 149, 135, 458, 243, 344]
[391, 480, 485, 358, 416, 269, 270, 354, 203, 436, 146]
[62, 132, 490, 33, 445, 97, 127, 274, 130, 77, 356]
[239, 11, 459, 245, 214, 0, 324, 162, 58, 394, 202]
[241, 395, 46, 78, 191, 384, 203, 191, 56, 474, 237]
[85, 480, 181, 98, 122, 482, 90, 351, 257, 266, 182]
[398, 125, 195, 423, 219, 290, 140, 166, 413, 499, 428]
[213, 367, 142, 471, 141, 407, 382, 229, 332, 455, 53]
[207, 12, 319, 54, 246, 274, 474, 312, 170, 374, 188]
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: Also, do you realize that a matrix with an even size has no center? (The example you show has `0` slightly off-center, with no center position possible.) A matrix with an odd size does have a center cell: Is that what you want?

Comment: Updated my question to add informations you asked. Hope it helps understand